# Determine remainder when items are shown in a grid - PHP

Tags: php, modulus

I have a loop which shows items in a grid of up to 12 items at a time (3 across by 4 rows down). There can be any number of items in the grid (1 to 12), but on instances where I have only 1 or 2 items on a row, I need to append a class to the HTML. For instance:

When I have 3,6,9,12 items - nothing required
When I have 4,7,10 items (1 remainder) - Items 4, 7 and 10 need a class applying
When I have 5,8,11 items (2 remainder) - Items 4,5, 7,8, 10,11 need a class applying

How can I do this in PHP. I have the following available to me for each item:

- Total number of products on page
- Current Item

Apologies - pseudo code as the editor garbles it:

```
$howmanyleft = totalproducts - currentproduct
if ($howmanyleft <= 2) {
    if ($currentproduct % 3 == 0) {
        //addclass
    }
}
```

Then in my CSS

```
article.product-single  {
    width: 33.3333%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(195,195,195);
    border-right: 1px solid rgb(195,195,195);
}
article.product-single:nth-child(3n) {
    border-right: none;
}

article.lastrow, article.product-single:last-child {
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

Sorry, I've got this wrong. This isn't what I need. My apologies. I just need any remaining items flagged with a class, not every row.

If there's 4 items, item 4 gets flagged
If there's 5 items, items 4 and 5 get flagged
If there's 10 items, item 10 gets flagged
If there's 11 items, items 10 and 11 get flagged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you would need some code like the following:

```
// check how many items will remain in the final row (if the row is not filled with 3 items)
$remainder = $total_items % 3;
for ($i = 0; $i < $total_items; $i++) { 
    if($remainder > 0 && $i >= $total_items - $remainder) {
        // executed for items in the last row, if the number of items in that row is less than 3 (not a complete row)
    } else {
        // executed for items that are in 3 column rows only
    }
}
```

Here is a complete example of how something like this would work. Create a new php file with the following code and see the output.

```
// add some random data to an array
$data = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven');
$total_items = count($data);

// check how many items will remain in the final row (if the row is not filled with 3 items)
$remainder = $total_items % 3;

// loop through all the items
for ($current_item = 0; $current_item < $total_items; $current_item++) { 
// check to see if the item is one of the items that are in the row that doesn't have 3 items
    if($remainder > 0 && $current_item >= $total_items - $remainder) {
        echo $data[$current_item] . " - item in last row, when row is not complete<br />";
    // code for regular items - the ones that are in the 
    } else {
        echo $data[$current_item] . " - item in filled row<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Lazar, this would have been ideal, but I've since changed by PHP slightly to append my classes in a simpler way.

Comment: Would you be willing to paste the part of the code we are talking about so I could give you a more adequate answer?

Comment: Of course. I'll update the question. The code is a JShop website (www.jshop.co.uk).

Comment: Let's go through the answer together and see what's troubling you..
If we do $total_items % 3, we would get the number of items that will remain after filling all rows with 3 items. So, if you have 10 items total, $remainder would be 1. Later, in the loop, we check if the $remainder was larger than 0 AND then we check the current item (in this case $i). If the current item is equal to or greater than ($total_items - $remainder) only then should you add classes to the items - meaning that the items that fit that criteria are in the last row and the row won't have 3 items. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It's simply number_of_products modulo number_of_columns

```
4 % 3 == 1
5 % 3 == 2
6 % 3 == 0
```

Comment: This was used combined with adding a 'lastrow' class to the items where n-total < 2 and n % 3 != 0